# Numbers.app Pop-Up Menu from Column?

Tags: numbers

I need to automate the following somehow, and I want to know if it's something that the software can accomplish:

I need to set a field in a table to a **Pop-Up Menu**, that is made up of entries in a column in another table.  It seems that the **Pop-Up Menu** can only be designed manually, as opposed to being defined in functions somehow.  Am I correct?

Does anybody have a way of achieving this?

Comment: A pop-up menu in a cell can not be defined via a function in Numbers, i.e. one can not write a formula in a cell that will make that cell act as a pop-up menu. What do you wish to achieve ultimately by using a formula in creating a pop-up menu?

Comment: I want a handy key field for a lookup.

Comment: Pulldown in T2F1 made from T1F1 -> lookup T1F3, and the lookup function places the result in T2F2.  FileMaker can do this sort of GUI population, if you know FMP.

Comment: This would be an extremely useful feature and it's a pain that it can't be done. In Excel, you can achieve this using the 'define names' feature and then assigning the variable name to the cell input. @Alper - a use case for this is for a simple timesheet or entry tool, where you're looking to record row data from a list. As your list changes over time (e.g. new clients coming on board), you'll want to update the data. It would be much cleaner to maintain a numbers sheet with config data that's looked up, rather than hard coding data into cells at the row level as one has to in numbers.